# How to Read Specific Range value of an Object Property

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

i'm new dealing with Ontologies and finding problems to get my SPARQL Query working , trying to read value of specific Object property that has multiple Ranges [Object Property Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs0cV.png)

trying this Query Return all Object Properties [Execution Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ4yA.png) , [Protege Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzhW4.png)

```
PREFIX ns: <http://www.semanticweb.org/pavilion/ontologies/2017/5/untitled-ontology-66#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
    ns:star1086 ns:possesses ?z .
}
```

The Desired Result that i want to read only the desired Range value, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're asking for. I mean, the first issue is that you used an object property for something that has literals as values? Any reason for it? And then, I don't get what your query should return now? The results of the query are of course URIs, so what's wrong with it? Are you hoping to get the numbers from the URIs?

Comment: Can you give the concrete data you want to get back?

Comment: By the way, there query language you're using here is called SPARQL and **not** GraphQL

Comment: Thanks for commenting , as you can see in the Execution result am getting multiple rows as result ( because the Object property has multiple ranges), what i want actually to do is to only get the Value of a specific Range of those ( e.g Temperature 1150 ) and not all of those Rows , Thanks .

Comment: your are mixing up terms here: the range of a property is a schema axiom, for your property you have multiple ranges defined: `SpectralType, StarTemperature, StarCoordinates, StarName` - which by the way is a clear modeling issues given that multiple ranges mean the intersection of all those classes. That can't be what you want. You have to use the union of those I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Next, your query retrieves all **values** for the property `possesses` of a particular individual.  Nothing more, nothing less. I mean, how could the query decide on which type of value you're interested in? That has to be reflected in the data.  I guess what you need here is an n-ary relation which in OWL is done by some intermediate individual. So, you have to create some individual like `possession1` which is of type `Temperature` and via a new property e.g. `ns:possessionValue` you attach the value `ns:1150` to it. Please read about n-ary relations in OWL, that's what you need

Comment: Thanks, @AKSW for your important time, I should mention that I'm a beginner, well what I understood so far that is not possible to read the specific Range, to do so I need to use a different property for each range instead?

Comment: either that or as I said, for the data you need some intermediate node which then itself has the type and the value. Please, read about n-ary relation in OWL. There are plenty of tutorials online I think. This will explain things much easier than I could do here.

Comment: you can also have a look at this: it shows what I mean by "intermediate node": https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/#vocabulary

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong about your ontology.

Specifying muliple ranges to your predicate creates an *intersection*. Take the following statement:

```
?star ns:possesses ?something
```

Then `?something` is a `SpectralType` **and** a `StarTemperature` **and** a `StarCoordinates` **and** a `StarName` at the same  time, which is not what you want.

Instead, you should use unions. Using unions, you can state that the object of a `ns:possesses` statement can be either a `SpectralType` **or** a `StarTemperature` **or** a `StarCoordinates` **or** a `StarName`. Then, in your SPARQL query you can write the following to get only statements from a single type.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ns:star1086 ns:possesses ?z .
    ?z a ns:SpectralType .
}
```

In Protégé, to write a union, open the class expression editor (by clicking on the "plus" next to "Ranges" for instance) and separate the different members with `or` :

```
SpectralType or StarTemperature or StarCoordinates or StarName
```

And click "OK" to create the new range.

---

## Further considerations

Let's take a step a back and look at your ontology.

You should not use a single predicate to store all these information in the first place. Instead, I suggest you use different sub-predicates so that your graphs and queries hold more semantic value.

Furthermore, `StarName` and `Temperature` are literal values. You should not use classes for that. Use datatype properties instead.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Richard-Degenne/3b4c7c7c24b85e0c3b5b37d269c5fc56) is a Gist you can download and open in Protégé. It contains some sample data so you can try the following SPARQL queries.

```
PREFIX : <http://www.richarddegenne.com/ontology/astronomy#>

# Get all statements about :star1086
SELECT * WHERE {
  :star1086 ?predicate ?object
}

# Get some statement about :star1086
SELECT * WHERE {
  VALUES ?predicate {
    :hasSpectralType :temperate
  }
  :star1086 ?predicate ?object
}

# Ask whether a given pattern is true
ASK WHERE {
  :star1086 :hasSpectralType :yellowDwarf
}

# Filter stars based on their temperature
# Note: You might want to add more stars with different temperature
#       if you want useful results.
SELECT ?star WHERE {
  ?star :temperature ?temperature
  FILTER(?temperature > 5000)
}
```